# Requisição HTTP funciona via POSTMAN mas NÃO funciona via android app

Tags: android, http-request, retrofit, okhttp, laravel-6

Eu tenho uma API para um aplicativo android que funcionou por um tempo.
Usava o Laravel 5.3 no server side e atualizamos para o 6.0.

Pelo aplicativo android, tenho de retorno o erro "400 - Bad Request", mas via postman ou Advanced REST Client a requisição funciona normalmente (com os mesmos parametros).

Outros sistemas também estão funcionando.

Estou usando:
Java Android
Retrofit 2
OkHTTP
GSON

> **Android app**

*interface LoginService*

```
@Headers({
        "Content-Type: application/json",
        "Accept: application/json"
})
@POST(Constants.API_LOGIN)
Call<Login> login(@Body Credentials credential);
```

*Credentials*

```
public class Credentials {

    // Atributos
    private String email;
    private String password;

    // GETs e SETs
    // Email
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    // Password
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    // Metodos
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "{\"email\":\"" + getEmail() + "\", \"password\":\"" + getPassword() + "\"}";
    }

}
```

*Login*

```
//        JsonObject json = new JsonObject();
//        json.addProperty("email", AUTH_USER);
//        json.addProperty("password", AUTH_PASS);
        Credentials credential = new Credentials();
        credential.setEmail(AUTH_USER);
        credential.setPassword(AUTH_PASS);

        Call<Login> call = new RetrofitConfig().getLoginService().login(credential);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<Login>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<Login> call, @NonNull Response<Login> response) {
                Login login = response.body();
                Log.d(TAG, "RESPONSE: " + response.message());
                String msg = "Autenticado com sucesso.";
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<Login> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + t.getMessage(), t);
                Toast.makeText(context, "Erro ao autenticar com servidor", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                call.cancel();
            }

        });
```

*POST Request*

```
D/OkHttp: --> POST https://inoprime.com.br/api/login/
D/OkHttp: Content-Type: application/json
    Accept: application/json
    Content-Length: 61
D/OkHttp: {"email":"EMAIL","password":"****"}
    --> END POST (60-byte body)
```

*Response*

```
D/OkHttp: <-- 400 https://inoprime.com.br/api/login/ (2130ms)
    server: awselb/2.0
    date: Wed, 15 Jan 2020 14:36:31 GMT
    content-type: text/html
    content-length: 138
D/OkHttp: <html>
    <head><title>400 Bad Request</title></head>
    <body bgcolor="white">
    <center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>
    </body>
    </html>
    <-- END HTTP (138-byte body)
```

> **Mesma requisição pelo Advanced REST Client**

*Request*

```
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
cookie: COOKIE
content-length: 61
POST https://inoprime.com.br/api/login/ HTTP/1.1
Host: HOST
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
cookie: COOKIE
content-length: 61

 {"email":"EMAIL","password":"***"}
```

*Response*

```
> 200 OK

{
"token": "TOKEN"
}
```

**Dados do ARC**
[image: Preenchimento dos dados da requisição no ARC]

**Retorno do ARC**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**LOG do ARC**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém consegue me ajudar?

Comment: Você fixou o Content-Length em 61: `"Content-Length: 61"` -- isso não me parece correto, quem tem que informar o content-length é a propria lib, checando o payload requisitado e não você, a não ser que você realmente saiba o que fez... Mas geralmente "bad request" (400) é má formação em algo no payload ou headers. E creio que o teu "log" feito no "Advanced REST Client" seja "falso", quero dizer, não tem sentido o "verbo" do HTTP (`POST /api/login/ HTTP/1.1`) estar no meio, ele é a primeira coisa a ser enviada pelo servidor de volta...

Comment: ...fora que tem um espaçamento na requisição HTTP antes do `{"email"`. Tem muita coisa ai que você pode ter digitado errado ao postar a pergunta, ou que realmente você está fazendo errado nos teus códigos.

Comment: O Content-length do ARC foi gerado sozinho... eu cheguei a copiar e colar no header do android para fins de teste... mas deu o mesmo resultado.

No ARC eu coloquei os parametros preenchendo o "formulario" do programa... e copiei o "resumo" q ele faz na requisição para facilitar a criar a pergunta...

No caso do /api/login, o stackoverflow me indicou a alteração suprimindo o host completo

Comment: Coloquei prints do ARC para exemplificar

Comment: Entendi, você na hora de copiar misturou tudo e embaralhou tudo na resposta que redigiu aqui, então o resto esta "certo".... Esta parte foi você quem escreve `@Headers({
        "Content-Type: application/json",
        "Accept: application/json",
        "Content-Length: 61"
})`? Ou isso é "gerado" também?

Comment: Posso fazer um sugestão? Cria um classe que recebe seu `email` e sua `password ` e passa essa `Class` no `@Body` em vez de `JsonObject `, faz esse teste e diz o que houve .

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento essa parte eu q escrevi msm... no incio, estava sem o Content-length, e deu a msm resposta... coloquei para ficar igual ao ARC msm...

Comment: @RicardoLucas tentarei aq

Comment: retirei o Content-Length: 61 e fiz uma classe de credencial e passei como parametro como o @RicardoLucas sugeriu. 
Obtive a mesma resposta

Comment: Posso está bem enganado mais me parece que pelo APP vocês está dando post direto na rota:
https://API O correto não seria na rota https://API/login ?

Comment: Qual o valor de `Constants.API_LOGIN`?

Comment: API_LOGIN = login/
API_HOST = https://inoprime.com.br/api/

Answer (score 1):

**Achei a solução!**

Eu inseria *header* **Authorization** nas configurações do Retrofit e estava funcionando perfeito.
Ao atualizar o Laravel para a versão 6.0, ao ser inserido o *Authorization* vazio (essa api/login era para gerar esse token) me retornava o erro *400 - Bad Request*.

Apenas fiz um if para retirar o *Authorization* quando não houver token e agora está perfeito! \o/

```
HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
interceptor.level(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor)
        .addInterceptor(chain -> {
            Request request;
            if (LoginManager.getToken().length() > 5) {
                request = chain.request().newBuilder()
                        .header("Authorization", LoginManager.getToken())
                        .build();
            } else {
                request = chain.request().newBuilder().build();
            }
            return chain.proceed(request);
        })
```

Answer (score -1):

Aqui eu estou usando `HttpURLConnection`, passando meus campos para:

```
String campos = URLEncoder.encode("campo1", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(valor_campo1, "UTF-8");
bufferedWriter.write(campos);
```

Dessa forma aqui funciona.

Comment: Como disse, via ARC ou outro meio funciona bem... esse app eh uma solução de um cliente (até grande)... e após a atualização do Laravel, essa requisição usando Retrofit 2 parou de funcionar...

Alterar o app inteiro não seria muito viável